# MIPS and RISC-V Differences

Tags: mips, riscv

I've been trying to learn RISC-V coming from MIPS and initially they don't look to dissimilar, especially the instruction set. Are there any significant differences between the two? Are most of the differences in the backend?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Section 2.16 of Patterson, D. A., & Hennessy, J. L. (2018). Computer organization and design: The hardware/software interface. Cambridge, MA: Morgan Kaufmann Publishers. (RISC-V edition):

> One of the main differences between RISC-V and MIPS is for conditional
> branches other than equal or not equal. Whereas RISC-V simply provides branch
> instructions to compare two registers, MIPS relies on a comparison instruction that
> sets a register to 0 or 1 depending on whether the comparison is true. Programmers
> then follow that comparison instruction with a branch on equal to or not equal
> to zero depending on the desired outcome of the comparison. Keeping with its
> minimalist philosophy, MIPS only performs less than comparisons, leaving it up to
> the programmer to switch order of operands or to switch the condition being tested by the branch to get all the desired outcomes. MIPS has both signed and unsigned
> versions of the set on less than instructions: slt and sltu.
>
> When we look beyond the core instructions that are most commonly used, the
> other main difference is that the full MIPS is a much larger instruction set than
> RISC-V [...]

Figure 2.29 from the book shows the slight differences in instruction formats for the MIPS and the RISC-V:

[image: Figure 2.29]

Comment: Why does MIPS use set-less-than and then jump-if instead of simply jump-if-less-than? It seems inefficient to take up both an extra instruction and an extra register.

Comment: @Zaz, I suppose in this case the two instructions (set-bit-after-comparison and conditional-jump-based-on-bit) leads to more functionality and simpler circuitry than instructions in the form of conditional-jump-after-comparison.  It would make more sense in the context of the particular instruction set architecture.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I want to add that is a bit more specific is that Immediate instructions with RISC-V use the upper 20 bits as compared to the upper 16 bit in MIPS.

For example in MIPS:

```
lui S0, 0x1234
S0 = 0x1234 0000
```

And in RISC-V its `S0 = 0x0123 4000`